A mystery movie took place in Sri Lanka
I'm looking for a mystery movie about some myth and its affects at present time. At the beginning of the movie there was a male narrator talking about a myth and meanwhile there were some scenes that relating to his sayings. He told something like that ; 
Many years ago, there was a little kingdom in South Asia. The princess of the kingdom had loved a poor and unemployed guy. They had decided to escape because they can't marry. The king had noticed that and alarmed his army. They had found them and killed the princess/guy. After that the curse of this forbidden love had remained of the responsibilities of this murder. 
After that scene, the movie started at present time. It was a USA made movie and probably between 1988-1998. The local people and actors look like Indian and it was an island so most likely the movie took place in Sri Lanka. There were tropical monsoon climate and the rains were sudden and heavy. 
There was an american married couple. They arrived to the island because of holiday or the business of the husband. I couldn't remember that. The husband was white, at his 40's, had fit body, had blue eyes and medium height. His wife was at her 30's, had blue eyes and medium blonde hair. She was taking pictures of the people, market place, landscapes, buildings, etc with her camera. Their relationship was good. They haven't got any kid but they were happy. They were kissing, having sex, making jokes, having fun, etc. 
They were staying at a hotel. It wasn't top quality but clean. The building hadn't got many floors and they were staying at 2nd or 3rd floor I guess. One night she had a nightmare about that myth which the narrator told. After that she changed psychologically, saw some visions couple of times and started to investigate that myth. 
One day they went to a restaurant. There was a fountain middle of the restaurant and there was a band playing ethnic rhymes. The tables were around the fountain and there were about 50 tables. After a while bunch of men also came in to the restaurant. Most of them were wearing military clothes. Their leader saw this american couple and expressed his greetings to see foreign people like them.
He looked like Indian, had military clothes, had dastar(turban) on his head, had medium beard and about 40 aged. He asked permission from the husband to let him dance with his wife. There was a slow ethnic song and they started to dance. He told some information about him and his country. The wife impressed about it and she kind of fallen love with him. 
Unfortunately I couldn't remember the rest of it. 

Ident questions are widely considered the bane of this site. This proves that wrong. This is everything we're looking for in an ident question +1 but only because I can't +10.
